# .Bat file to execute macro from attachmate EXTRA application

Tags: batch-file, attachmate-extra

How to execute macro file (.ebm) using batch script ?

Attachmate extra application has macro recording option after recording it saves .ebm file (macro) in local system. I have written a batch file to execute this macro. But its not working.

Thanks in advance!!

How I do it manually - I goes to the application in the folder and double click opens the attachmate application, when click on "Tools" option it displays list of recorded macros from that list I click on a macro to execute it. How can I automate this using batch script. please suggest

Solution found, Updated the script below.

```
start "" - After start command, you can give title or empty string (Thanks to compo for help)
extra.exe - This will open your aplication
/h <hostname> - Find your hostname/ip address in Options>Settings>Connection
/m macro path - Which macro you need to execute
```

**Updated Batch script**

```
@echo off

start "" extra.exe /h "tplxsuper.xyz.com" /m "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Attachmate\EXTRA!\macros\HELLO.EBM"
exit
```

Comment: When you use `Start` the first string enclosed within doublequotes is seen as a title, for that reason, you should include a title, even an empty one, thus: `@Start "" "%PUBLIC%\Documents\Attachmate\EXTRA!\sessions\tplxsuper.edp" /m "%PUBLIC%\Documents\Attachmate\EXTRA!\macros\HELLO.EBM"`

Comment: @Compo Appreciate your effort to answer my question! by adding " " It is launching the attachmate application only, Am not able to execute macros from it. while I can do it manually

Comment: I wasn't answering your question, _those go in the answer section_, I commented only on the correct syntax for the `Start` command as seen in the usage information when you enter `Start /?` in the Command prompt. Perhaps you should explain, _in an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49945109/edit) to your question_, how do you do it manually, so that we could translate that into possible answers.

Comment: Do you usually run for example `Extra.exe` providing that with your `.edp` file and optional startup macro parameter? e.g. `Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\E!PC\Extra.exe" /nologo "%PUBLIC%\Documents\Attachmate\EXTRA!\sessions\tplxsuper.edp" /m "%PUBLIC%\Documents\Attachmate\EXTRA!\macros\HELLO.EBM"`

Comment: @Compo Thanks for the suggestion.. I have edited my question to describe how I do it manually.

Comment: When google about this I found this solution, but its not working for me.You have to start 'extra.exe' with these parameters: /h <host name or ip address> /m <macro>

Suppose extra.exe is in ..\Attachmate\EXTRA! then your command line would be:

start "C:\Program Files\Attachmate\EXTRA!\extra.exe" /h "C:\Program Files\Attachmate\EXTRA!\Sessions\ENU\tn3270.edp" /m "C:\Documents and Settings\perkinj\My Documents\Attachmate\EXTRA!\macros\CAPTUR32.EBM"

See [https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7021248] for reference.

Comment: When you go to `the application in the folder and double click` if the application is called `Extra` and the application folder is named `E!PC` and is located in  `C:\Program Files` then try the command I provided in my previous comment. If not, you need to provide those names and location information!

Comment: Thanks Compo, Finallly figured it out.. I entered my hostname and issue resolved now..@echo off

start "" extra.exe /h "tplxsuper.xyz.com" /m "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Attachmate\EXTRA!\macros\HELLO.EBM"
exit

Comment: If you are just `exit`ing immediately afterwards there's no real need in that case for the `start` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it. Take your macro and change the file extension from .ebm to .elf your macro will be executable from a BAT or VBS file.

Comment: Here is a copy of one I use, "H:\INFOConnect\ram\signonS.elf"